# What is the ANSI standard SQL equivalent of UNPIVOT?

Tags: sql, t-sql, unpivot, ansi-sql

In T-SQL, `PIVOT` is redundant because you can always replace it with a combination of `CASE WHEN` and `GROUP BY`. I presume that the same is true of `UNPIVOT`. If I had some T-SQL `UNPIVOT` code that I wanted to conform to the SQL standard (let's say, the current ANSI), what would I replace the `UNPIVOT` with? My best guess so far is some usage of `UNION ALL`?

A good answer would show a quick example of such a conversion.

Comment: Yes, `UNION ALL` is typically used.

Comment: Yes, it can be replaced by `UNION ALL`, but the specifics depend on the implementation details. For example, SQL Server filters out `NULL` values from the source and those will not be shown in the result.

Comment: Yes - see `unpivot the data` here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7233/sql-pivot-sql-unpivot-examples-transform-data/ (note: they use `union` instead of `union all`... that would have the side effect of removing any duplicates from the results (e.g. as would happen if you included `distinct`... though generally the data used for an unpivot wouldn't be likely to have duplicates anyway, so it's probably not an issue which is used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `UNPIVOT` such as this:

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM YourTable AS t
UNPIVOT (
    ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (
        Unpivot1, Unpivot2, Unpivot3
    )
) AS u;
```

You can do the same thing with a Lateral Join and a `VALUES` constructor

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM YourTable AS t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES
    ('UnPivot1', t.Unpivot1),
    ('UnPivot2', t.Unpivot2),
    ('UnPivot3', t.Unpivot3)
) AS u(ColumnName, ColumnValue);
```

In SQL Server this can be done using `CROSS APPLY`

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM YourTable AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('UnPivot1', t.Unpivot1),
    ('UnPivot2', t.Unpivot2),
    ('UnPivot3', t.Unpivot3)
) AS u(ColumnName, ColumnValue);
```

I normally recommend this method even in SQL Server, as it's much more flexible. For example, you can unpivot multiple columns at a time.

---

Exactly which product you are using that supports ANSI-SQL *perfectly* is a different question, I'm not aware of any that do. you are best off just using the syntax that your product provides.

Comment: For the sake of comparison, you might want to edit in the equivalent `UNPIVOT`.

Comment: Done that now..

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the only gap is the lack of any mention of the `union all` solutions that the comments on the question mention, but I think it's obvious how to do that anyway.

Comment: I didn't mention it mainly because it's not *equivalent*, it's an alternative query which will read the base table multiple times. These options do not, the base table is only read once.